# how to compile CUDA to llvm IR?

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, llvm, clang

I've been trying for three days to compile a CUDA kernel into llvm IR and I couldn't do it. I've changed  `langoptions.cpp` and added `CUDA=1;` in the constructor , but still the clang give me Error messages for cuda syntax (like _synchthreads() call).
I've done the following:

1. downloaded llvm (including clang) modified langoptions.cpp (CUDA=1;
   in the constructor), and installed it.
2. installed CUDA toolkit 4.1 and CUDA SDK.
3. compiled a CUDA example using clang using:

   ```
   clang -I${CUDA_HOME}/include -I${CUDA_SDK_INC}
   ~/workspace/cuda_example/mis_kernel.cu -S -emit-llvm -o
   ~/workspace/cuda_example/a.ll
   ```

and as I said it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`clang –x=CUDA` in the public LLVM trunk is something experimental done outside of NVIDIA; you should contact the llvm-dev alias with questions.

NVCC doesn't support emitting LLVM IR.

Comment: hi harri, trunk llvm currently has the nvptx target (i presume the one published by Justin Holewinski; http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2012-April/049215.html) so i presume now its possible to build CUDA with clang? or there is work that needs to be done yet on the clang frontend?